# Analytically calculate the zero energy edge states of the Su-Schrieffer-Heeger model

Tags: condensed-matter, topological-insulators

Is it possible to analytically calculate (or verify the existence of) zero energy edge states for the SSH model in real space? This seems to be discussed in Section 1.5.2 of "A Short Course on Topological Insulators" ([link](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-25607-8), [open access](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.02295)), but I don't follow the logic and it also doesn't seem to quite be the SSH model.

Comment: Try solving the Schroedinger equation in recursion.